Proper way to configure /etc/hosts on Debian 12?
I'm trying to set the hostname and FQDN in /etc/hosts. Do I use the 127.0.0.1 IP or the LAN IP instead?
127.0.0.1 hostname hostname.domain
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain

or
192.168.1.6 hostname hostname.domain
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain


In the post
Include domain name or not in /etc/hosts?
the answer by phemmer recommended this setting:

In a nutshell, if you want fully qualified hostname to work, you
should do either:
127.0.0.1 fully.qualified.hostname hostname localhost.localdomain localhost

or
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
1.2.3.4 fully.qualified.hostname hostname


